# Android sdk manager not fetching other sdk platform

Tags: android

I downloaded the `SDK ADT` bundle for windows, everything is working well but `Android SDK Manager` is showing error

> Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-7.xml, reason: SSLPeerUnverified peer not authenticated

As I want to install other android platform.

Comment: Seems to me like you are behind a proxy which does not allow you to connect to this location. Or you did not specify proxy settings in eclipse. cfr. http://www.mkyong.com/web-development/how-to-configure-proxy-settings-in-eclipse/

Comment: Can you open the url with a browser ?

Comment: Running into the same problem, on mac osx, can't find good help nowhere. so far only had trouble trying to get the android SDK.. ugh

Comment: In Mac OS X, create the file ~/.android/androidtool.cfg manually and add this line to it:
sdkman.force.http=true

Comment: @Snicolas, I have the same problem and I can open the url with the browser.

Comment: @eeshwr, after 2 years I don't remember, but I don't have this issue anymore. Sorry.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Try using "http" instead of "https".
Go to the `Android SDK Manager -> Tools -> Options...` and check `"Force https://... sources to be fetched using http://..."`.

[image]

Also, you can set your proxy settings, if any.

Comment: In the ADT version I have (downloaded 1/2014), this dialog is at Android SDK Manager -> Preferences... on Mac OS/X and the Eclipse version that shows curly braces for the icon.

Comment: where do you find this window?

Comment: After doing this, I don't receive any updates anymore.

Comment: it not saved after exit

Comment: Thank you @Luis Valdés

Answer (score 22):

In Mac OS X, the solution is creating the file androidtool.cfg in our user .android folder and then add this line. Sure it is working also for Linux

**sdkman.force.http=true**

I hope that helps!

Comment: This works for osx when using the tools/android application to manage sdks

Comment: SHould we remove that opening as soon as done ? Because we disable SSL for any android tool, right ?

Comment: any way of doing this on windows?

Answer (score 3):

Open the terminal and put this:

```
root@gl:/etc/ssl/certs/java# keytool -list -keystore cacerts
Enter keystore password: [your pass]

Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 0 entries
```

Note: the default password for the keystore is “changeit”.
Fix: To properly build the keystore with all trusted CA certificates, run this:

```
root@gl:~# rm /etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts
root@gl:~# /var/lib/dpkg/info/ca-certificates-java.postinst configure
```

You should see a long list of added certificates (*.pem) and finally a “done”.Problem solved.

Found this [here](https://justus.berlin/2015/01/connection-problems-with-ssltls-peers-in-java-on-ubuntu-server-14-12-with-fix/).

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be a problem on Ubuntu (perhaps other Debian-based distros) with the Java CACerts keystore.  For some reason this does not always include the full list of entries.

To solve this, try the following:

- Delete the cacerts file

  `sudo rm /etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts`
- Re-build the cacerts file using the dpkg postinstall script:

  `sudo /var/lib/dpkg/info/ca-certificates-java.postinst configure`

This should re-generate the cacerts file and the problem should be resolved.

Answer (score 1):

If the force http doesn't work (like in my case) try clearing or unchecking the Manifest Cache in the options menu. That resolved it for me

Answer (score 1):

I'm an user from China. **Force to use http** doesn't work for me.

I set **proxy** in SDK Tool's option, which unexpectedly works!! Actually I have set proxy in Internet Options. This doesn't work alone.

So my solution for China users now is as following(Windows only, Mac users please try your own way):

1. Set proxy in **Internet Options**
2. Set proxy for Android SDK Manager. Tools--Options--Proxy setting.

---------------------------divider line for some complain-----------------------

All these things are so frustrating...

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Mac osx and you still get error. Simply disable your proxy setting from System Preferences and **just** set proxy inside SDK Manager through one of the mentioned ways. Restart your SDK Manager and it will ask you for proxy credentials.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem today, installing the last JDK and setting de environment variables JAVA_HOME and JDK_HOME to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92 (wich is the installation path of the last JDK) and changing the JDK segment of PATH solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, you can fix it with:

```
 ./android update sdk --no-ui -s
```

Also you will get tips with:

```
 ./android update sdk --help

inmyfree@INMYFREE:/usr/local/bin/android-sdk-linux/tools$ sudo ./android update sdk --help
Error: Flag '--help' is not valid for 'update sdk'.

       Usage:
       android [global options] update sdk [action options]
       Global options:
  -s --silent     : Silent mode, shows errors only.
  -v --verbose    : Verbose mode, shows errors, warnings and all messages.
     --clear-cache: Clear the SDK Manager repository manifest cache.
  -h --help       : Help on a specific command.

                     Action "update sdk":
  Updates the SDK by suggesting new platforms to install if available.
Options:
  -f --force     : Forces replacement of a package or its parts, even if
                   something has been modified.
  -n --dry-mode  : Simulates the update but does not download or install
                   anything.
     --proxy-host: HTTP/HTTPS proxy host (overrides settings if defined)
  -s --no-https  : Uses HTTP instead of HTTPS (the default) for downloads.
  -t --filter    : A filter that limits the update to the specified types of
                   packages in the form of a comma-separated list of
                   [platform, system-image, tool, platform-tool, doc, sample,
                   source]. This also accepts the identifiers returned by
                   'list sdk --extended'.
  -u --no-ui     : Updates from command-line (does not display the GUI)
     --proxy-port: HTTP/HTTPS proxy port (overrides settings if defined)
  -p --obsolete  : Deprecated. Please use --all instead.
  -a --all       : Includes all packages (such as obsolete and non-dependent
                   ones.)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue with Ubuntu and OpenJDK and the workaround with "Force [...] http" worked for me, but i think that is from security perspective not the best solution, so i looked for another way to fix it:

The Problem is, that somehow the Google's Issuing CA certificate is missing in the Java Keystore, which is important for the SSL connection.

To solve the problem first download the Google's Issuing CA certificate from Googles Website https://pki.google.com 
Then open a Terminal and move to /etc/ssl/certs/java

```bash
cd /etc/ssl/certs/java/
```

In this location is the Java-keystore. The file is called "cacerts". Now you have to add the previously downloaded certificate to the keystore with this command

```bash
sudo keytool -import -alias googleCA -file /yourdownloadlocation/GIAG2.crt -keystore cacerts
```

If you hadn't changed the password before, the standard password for the keystore is "changeit".
After you added the certificate, you should be able to use https to fetch the files.